# how to set unique id for multiple form using JQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have more than 1 form in my page. i submit this forms using ajax to database. the problem is each of this form should have unique id in order to submit with ajax(JQuery id selector), and the first form always get submitted using ajax and other form submitted with php. how can i have unique id for each form and submit all forms with AJAX?

```
<form action="inc/new.comment.php" method="post" id="new_comment_answer_form">
    <textarea name="new_answer" id="new_answer" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="enter your new answer"></textarea>
    <!-- <input type="text" name="comment_author" id="comment_author" placeholder="author name"> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="<?php echo $comment_id ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_answer" value="send" id="submit_answer">
</form>
<p id="new_answer_result"></p>
```

jQUERY:

```
 $("#new_comment_answer_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var new_answer = $("#new_answer").val();
        var submit_answer = $("#submit_answer").val();
        var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
        var comment_id = $("#comment_id").val();
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {});
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {});
        $.post("./inc/new.comment.php", {
            new_answer: new_answer,
            submit_answer: submit_answer,
            post_id: post_id,
            comment_id: comment_id
        }, function (data, status) {
            $("#new_answer_result").html(data);
            $("#new_answer").val("");
        });
    });
```

use of this code is comment on other comments in a blog site.(if that helps)

Comment: It is possible to submit forms without id. $("form").each(function(){$(this).submit(...)});

Comment: @alex can you be more specific?

Comment: @Technotures I hope my edit clarifies it because I wasn't sure what the original wording actually meant.

Comment: @mike. thanks. my bad, English is not my first language!

Comment: to submit all forms with AJAX just use $("form").submit(...). The Id is not needed to  process all forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give for each your form unique IDs, but set the same class, for example class="submit_form". Next you should call the function by this class. Other fields you can call by names.

```
$(".submit_class").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_answer = $(this).find("[name=new_answer]").val();
    var submit_answer = $(this).find("[name=submit_answer]").val();
    var post_id = $(this).find("[name=post_id]").val();
    var comment_id = $(this).find("[name=comment_id]").val();
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {});
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {});
    $.post("./inc/new.comment.php", {
        new_answer: new_answer,
        submit_answer: submit_answer,
        post_id: post_id,
        comment_id: comment_id
    }, function (data, status) {
        $("#new_answer_result").html(data);
        $(this).find("[name=new_answer]").val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: this just prevent form from submitting using php. but since i have more than 1 form, if i want to submit second form, the value of the first form get submitted.

Comment: Edited code to submit values from each form, you can access to them with [name] selector. See above

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have the form creation code in loop.

try this..

```
<?php i=0; // take post_id, if you want ?>

<form action="inc/new.comment.php" method="post" id="new_comment_answer_form_<?php echo ++i; ?>">
    <textarea name="new_answer" id="new_answer" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="enter your new answer"></textarea>
    <!-- <input type="text" name="comment_author" id="comment_author" placeholder="author name"> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="<?php echo $comment_id ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_answer" value="send" id="submit_answer">
</form>
<p id="new_answer_result"></p>
```

You will have different id as "new_comment_answer_form_1", "new_comment_answer_form_2".

Answer (score 0):

You can submit multiple forms with php as well.

at the top of your file.php

```
if(isset($_POST['btnName1'])){

  ... manipulate form's content

}elseif(isset($_POST['btnName2'])){

  ... manipulate another forms content
}
```

then later on in your file have the forms, they don't even need ID, php will recognise form by button name tag

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="inputField">
<input type="submit" name="btnName1">
</form>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="inputField">
<input type="submit" name="btnName2">
</form>
```